# Can I use a C1100T modem as a wifi extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem

I have a C4000Z modem as my DSL interface, and an older C1100T modem that I'd like to use as a (wired) wifi extender node. I've tried various setups, including using transparent bridging on the C1100T, which seems to work for a while but then the modems seem to either fight for the DSL interface or start performing DHCP assignment in conflict, which throws me off DSL and creates chaos in the network.
Any suggestions in what I am missing? I thought perhaps I could assign (on the C4000Z) a static IP address to the C1100T and limit the DHCP address space the C1100T uses, so that both modems could perform DHCP processing but not conflict.

Comment: You need to disable DHCP in the secondary.